# QDirIterator skips files

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Basically, I do this:

Check C:\Windows directory properties:
Size: 22.6 GB (24,281,251,244 bytes), Files: 154,028 Files

Then, using the following code, I try to achieve same numbers:

```
inline uint64_t file_size(std::string fname)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(fname, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
    return ifs.tellg();
}
...
QDirIterator it (path_, QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden | QDir::System , QDirIterator::Subdirectories | QDirIterator::FollowSymlinks);
while (it.hasNext())
{
    QFileInfo info(it.next());
    // QFileInfo::size is messed up for *.lnk files, had to improvise
    uint64_t size;
    if (info.isSymLink())
        size = file_size(info.absoluteFilePath().toStdString());
    else
        size = info.size();

    current_sz_desc_.full_size_ += size;
    current_sz_desc_.file_count_ ++;
}
```

What I get: 21,788,122,091 bytes, Files: 148823

It works for all user-created directories, but somehow fails for system ones (Program Files, Windows, etc). What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hi im assuming here by the code you shared that you have enough experience to see what i did and be able to reproduce the concept for your own idea(i didnt put full code just what it need to be see. **http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstorageinfo.html#bytesTotal** | **http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdir.html** (keep it simple as you can , the complexity of your script should be equal to the complexity of the task asked) this script will look any directory(including program file system) but not the hided ones

```
int count = 0 ;
QString Root ;

 void MyFunction()
{
    QStorageInfo storage = QStorageInfo::root() ;

    qDebug() << storage.rootPath();
    /*bytes will be only once /1000 not /1000/1000*/
    qDebug() << "size:" << storage.bytesTotal()/1000/1000 << "MB"; 
    qDebug() << "name:" << storage.name();
    qDebug() << "fileSystemType:" << storage.fileSystemType();
    qDebug() << "availableSize:" << storage.bytesAvailable()/1000/1000 << "MB";

    Root = storage.rootPath() ; 

    QDirIterator Load_Path(Root, QDirIterator::Subdirectories) ;

    do
    {
      count = count + 1 ;
      qDebug() << count ; 
    }while(Load_Path.hasNext()) ;
}
```

Comment: with QDir::Hidden  i got no debug output nothing even the file i suppose to generate of doesnt create(in my full script i log all path)

Comment: with QDir::AllEntries does not give hidden path i just test it

Comment: im wondering you know recycle.bin is hidden path but to access it or even do something in this path from cmd you need admin privilege , may its the same thing may the program as not enough authority  im still looking i think is that cause the line  'QDirIterator Load_Path(Root, QDirIterator::Subdirectories) ;' look for any directories from root so it suppose to show them like i say i think its more a privilege kind of problem ,i also read and try most of QDir & QDirIterator and theres nothing about hidden file

Comment: i did not find anything on hided folder files etc. or its a privilege problem or thats i was thinking while smoking outside(5min ago) if its hided its hided its meant to not be found or mess with

Comment: Well, I tried this with admin authority, it didn't work.

Comment: The one I wrote lost about 3 GB of space inside System32 directory.

Comment: Problem is, I don't need space value only. I need extension-based statistics on filesystem, and that means iterating through files directly.

Comment: when you say you need a extension-based statistics do you mean you want to know how much .exe it as or how much .dll or wte .bat its just example

Comment: i just thinked about it windows path and system file are always the same in each computer they part of window(they differ version to version) do you are able to start the scan a the root of the hidden folder ?

Comment: i just test to launch a scan in C:\ProgramData wich is hided and it show me all path with extension